# Knockout.js : observable.subscribe with window.location.reload() causes infinite reload loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a dropdown (select / option) which should do a full page refresh (reload) when changed.. (I'm setting a cookie value when changed...)

**What happens :**

When i use window.location.reload() inside the subscribe (see code below), it ends up in a infinite reload loop..

How can i avoid this ?

**Select control**

```
<select id="ddlSelectDepartment" class="form-control" data-bind="options: departments, optionsCaption: 'Alle', optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedDepartment"></select>
```

**Knockout handling**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var selDepCookie = JSHelpers.readCookie("seldep");
console.log("COOKIEMONSTER! " + selDepCookie);

var DepModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.departments = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedDepartment = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedDepartment.subscribe(function (latest) {
        //console.log("Input changed");
        JSHelpers.setCookie('seldep', latest);
        window.location.reload();  // this ends in a infinite loop !
    }, self);
}

var urlForSelectDepartment = 'api/Customer/GetDepartmentsFull';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlForSelectDepartment,
    success: function (data) {
        depmodel.departments(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
});

var depmodel = new DepModel();
ko.applyBindings(depmodel, 
document.getElementById("selectDepartmentContainer"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the initial value of selectedDepartment to undefined instead of 0. Right now your dropdown list is being rendered with an initial value that doesn't exist in the list of options (since the options arrive later from an ajax call) so it is having to modify the selectedDepartment observable from 0 to undefined which is firing your subscription.

```
self.selectedDepartment = ko.observable(undefined);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @James Spake, it actually worked.. !! :) Now i just have to find some logic to fetch the cookie, and set selected value to the dropdown...

Comment: The only question is have left is... when i did like this : self.selectedDepartment = ko.observable(JSHelpers.readCookie("seldep")); It ended in a infinite loop again..

Comment: How can i set the selected value in the dropdown to the value of the cookie ?

Comment: @TerjeNygård You just need to make sure that the value you're setting already exists in the departments array so that the dropdown finds it in the list when the initial value is set.